# Photos - convert shared albums to private albums?

Tags: photos, photos.app

How do I convert shared albums to private albums in the Photos app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shared album cannot be *converted* to a private album.

- Create a new (private) album
- Copy the contents from the shared to the private album
- Delete the shared album

Comment: My Photos.app crashes when attempting to do this, using any method (dragging the shared album onto the private album, dragging the files onto the private album, copy-pasting the files into the private album…) – is this a known and common weakness in the app, or might something else be wrong in this case?

Comment: This does not work. When you try and paste, nothing happens. Have you actually tested this method?

Comment: @CharlesRobertson Both drag&drop and cmd+C&cmd+V work for me (just tested on macOS Sonoma)